# Kotlin, Android: runOnUiThread() seemingly appears to not be functioning when called from okhttp3 API Call

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, okhttp

I am new to both Kotlin, multithreading, and android studio.
I am using the `okhttp3` dependency to call an API. The call is done with a URL that is partially determined by user input, in the UI. I, therefore, want to validate the response in case of user error.

The user is requested to input a sequence of 9 integers that represents his or her player ID in the database that the application is talking to.
One of the possible error that can occur is that the user inputs a user ID that is 9 characters long but does not hold any of the specific data I am looking for.

The current Kotlin code (in MainActivity) to validate the user inputted player ID, which happens IN the call, is as follows:

```kotlin
private fun fetchShipIDJson() {
        println("Attempting to fetch Ship name JSON")

        val shipIdURL = "http://api.worldofwarships.eu/wows/ships/stats/?application_id= APPLICATION ID REMOVED &in_garage=1&account_id=$playerId"

        val shipIdRequest = Request.Builder().url(shipIdURL).build()

        //Ship ID call
        okHttpClientVar.newCall(shipIdRequest).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("failed to execute ship ID request")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                println("ship ID request completed successfully")

                shipIdBody = response?.body?.string()

                //Incorrect player ID input gives Null data
                if (shipIdBody?.contains("\"$playerId\":null}")!! || shipIdBody?.contains("\"$playerId\": null}")!!) {

                    println("first exception condition met")

                    runOnUiThread {
                        giveUserInputFeedback("playerId returns null data or does not exist", 1)
                    }

                }
etc.
```

when the user input:  "123456789" is given in the virtual machine the log does print "first exception condition met". Therefore I am concluding that the flow is correct.

Finally, the problem is this: in order to call my functionality to provide the user with feedback I have to call `runOnUiThread` because the code breaks because: *"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."* occurs otherwise.

However, `runOnUiThread` does not appear to do anything or results in anything.

I have also substituted the full expression for the lambda expression in the code but it also appeared to not function.

```kotlin
runOnUiThread(object : Runnable { override fun run() { println("testing complete runnable expression instead of lambda") } })
```

How can I get around this so I can call my `giveUserInputFeedback()` function when the exception is encountered?

Comment: Is your main thread starved e.g. busy doing something else?

Comment: I checked in the profiler of Android studio. My CPU appears to be at 0% once it gets to the above mentioned point in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

The API call that you're trying to is done on another thread(background) when you do `okHttpClientVar.newCall(shipIdRequest).enqueue` here enqueue will run the api call on background thread and while you're getting your API response meanwhile you're trying to manipulate your view or do some task with the response which is not received yet, while you're on another thread and by explicitly specifying to `runOnUiThread {}`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63216344/7820756) you can get some reference from one of my answers where you can use callback approach to perform your task.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response. I, however, must be misunderstanding something. The response of ```shipIdBody``` should be already received, since this is all handled within ```onResponse```  as I understand it currently. When the ```shipIdBody``` is printed in the console before runOnUiThread, its expected value is there. Or is it perhaps the case that all the code within  ```onResponse``` must be completed before the asynchronous task is considered complete?

Comment: Can you tell me what is happening in "giveUserInputFeedback()" because according to what it seems like is you're trying to do some changes in your view here? or is it something else? because right now things are a bit unclear here .

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. ```giveUserInputFeedback()``` takes ```feedbackMessage: String``` and a ```status: Int``` as parameters.  It simply modifies a text field in the UI to display the feedback message, which is colored green when ```status``` is 0, indicating no error, and red when the ```status ``` is 1 and there is an error.

Comment: Okay so like i said you're changing your UI on a API call that is being executed on another thread created by the enqueue call , but right now without better understanding of your actual code and logic, things are a bit unclear have you tried using call back approach like i've mentioned instead of calling runOnUiThread{} and performing your UI changes when data has been successfully received.